# One-to-many relationship in Grocery CRUD

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

There are examples on the Grocery CRUD website of a [one-to-one relationship](http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/set_a_relation) and a [many-to-many relationship](http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/set_a_relation_n_n), but no example of a one-to-many relationship.

Here is an example: I have `car_makes` and `car_models` tables. Each `model_id` may only belong to one `make_id`. Each `make_id` can be associated with many `model_id`s.

SQFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c357c

Now, I try to set up Grocery CRUD:

```
public function cars(){
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table("car_makes");
    $crud->set_relation("make_id","car_models","model_name");
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);    
    }
```

This doesn't work -- in the grid view, the `make_id` is suddenly replaced with a `model_name`, and it's totally wrong. For example, I'm seeing the "Ford Volt" when I clearly specified the `model_name` Volt is associated with `make_id` 2, and `make_id` 2 has a `make_name` of Chevrolet. When viewing a single record, only one make is visible, when there should be a list.

What I really want to do is make it easy to add additional models to car makes, and see what models are already associated with a make.

How should I configure Grocery CRUD to handle this 1-n relationship?

I need to avoid a many-to-many relationship, because a model may not belong to more than one make. Thanks.

**EDIT:** A colleague suggests handling models through a model list instead of part of the makes list would be the way to go. This seems reasonable, but less useful.

**EDIT 2:** Here's the code that allows you to look up a model and assign a make to it:

```
public function car_models(){
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table("car_models");
    $crud->set_relation("make_id","car_makes","make_name");
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);
    }
```

Now, I really think it should be the other way around -- you look up a make and assign models to it -- but I don't think Grocery CRUD supports that for 1-n relationships when using set_relation(). That is supported for many-to-many relationships, where you can look up 1 movie and assign many actors to it. Perhaps by using set_relation_n_n() this can be accomplished?

Comment: I would suggest you to check this [MY_Model.php](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model).

Comment: Wow. Come on folks. @Tpojka recommends I use a different framework and Indrasinh Bihola recommends I read the documentation on how to install Grocery CRUD? These are both useless suggestions.

Comment: So are you able to use grocery store library with codeigniter?? In your code I am not able to figure out whether you have integrate it properly or not that's why I suggest you documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link Grocery CRUD do provide one-to-many relationship and it is also explain everywell using example. set_relation function is for 1-n i.e. one-to-many relationship only, see in documentation it is written in it.

[set_relation](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation)

This is the function and parameter you need to follow

```
set_relation( string $field_name , string  $related_table, string  $related_title_field  [, mixed $where [, string $order_by ] ] )
```

1st parameter should be field name, 2nd is relation table, and 3rd is relation table field name that need to be displayed. Other parameters are optional and you can also use that.

Go through the documentation properly you will surely get it.

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't make sense. In my example, I want to manage a list of the car models in the car makes record editor. Please expand this example with the full PHP function that would allow me to do this. As it is, I can set a make for each model, but I can't easily see which makes belong to the model.

Comment: It looks like the set_relation is for one to one relation ?! is it ?